# Powershell Date

Tags: powershell

I have a personalized powershell profile, on my $PROFILE I have added the Get-Date command and it gives me the date at the moment the script is executed, I wanted to know if it is possible to have the time updated every second or five and still being able to use the powershell, Ive tried a lot of possibilities but cant find one that works, if thi is not possible is there anything similar?
thanks.

ive tried a lot of whiles, jobs ...
here some examples of what I have tried:

```
$script = {
    while ($true) {
        Write-Output (Get-Date -Format G)
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    }
}

Start-Job -ScriptBlock $script
```

```
while ($true) {
    Write-Host (Get-Date -Format G) -NoNewline
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    Write-Host "`r" -NoNewline
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could modifiy the prompt function for this. This way it won't interfere with commands output and the terminal.

Check current definition with:
`(Get-Command prompt).ScriptBlock`

It should be something like this:

```
"PS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) ";
```

Then modify it for current session only (just paste and execute in terminal):

```
function prompt {
"$(get-date -f 'G') PS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) ";
}
```

prompt before:

```
PS C:\Users\username>
```

prompt after:

```
2023-02-09 16:13:13 PS C:\Users\username>
```

If it works as expected, you can place new function definition in `$PROFILE`. This way you'll always have the time of all meaningful events, i.e. every command/script start and completion.

Comment: That's cool but I already have the oh-my-posh plugin that does the same, it would be cool that it could update the time every second, as if it was a digital clock on the console